# Problem with chaining relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have three models and relationships. Post, UserProfile, User. I need to fetch name column value from users table but I need to go through posts and user profile to fetch it. Posts are connected to user profile and user profile is connected to users. I tried $post->userProfile()->user()->name but it won't work. I get error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\BelongsTo::user()
```

Here is my code. Any help is appreciated.

Post.php

posts table has user_profile_id column

```
public function userProfile()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(UserProfile::class);
}
```

UserProfile.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id');
}

public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

User.php

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class, 'id');
}
```

Comment: What is `$posts`? Single post or collection?

Comment: @Lessmore Single post.

Comment: What happens if `profile()` changed to `userProfile()` in User.php

Comment: Do not use parenthesis, use $post->userProfile->user->name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use the dynamic properties to access the actual resolved relationship (Model or Collection) and not the relationship methods:

```
$post->userProfile->user->name
```

This would assume these relationships are setup correctly and exist in the database.

If you are using PHP8 you can use the existential operator to avoid the issue of a relationship returning `null` and calling methods on that:

```
$post->userProfile?->user?->name
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
// Lets get the post having id 1
$post = Post->find(1);
$post->userProfile->user->name;
```

When you are using parenthesis, you will get you the Eloquent relationship itself, not the results of that relationship.

> $post->userProfile();

If you wanted to get user's profile information of that post by using parenthesis, then use this code.

```
$post->userProfile()->get(); //or
$post->userProfile()->first();
```